# How to add libcurl dependency without getting bound to openssl version

Tags: c, curl, openssl, libcurl

I compile my Linux app on Debian Wheezy. It runs and works on all Linux distros.

Recently, I added a dependency of libcurl (needed to make some https requests), now my app doesn't work on Linux distros which don't have libssl.so.1.0.0 present like fedora ships OpenSSL version 1.1.

I just needed a libcurl dependency and got caught in this openssl version issue. My app doesn't care which OpenSSL lib is installed, it just needs libcurl to run, so is this possible to add libcurl.so as a dependency only and installed libcurl will automatically use the ssl lib it was compiled for.

Comment: compile in libcurl & openssl statically?

Answer (score 0):

Your app does not care about which OpenSSL is installed - but LIBCURL does ;-)

So, in order to use libcurl as you are expecting, I guess you will have to use libcurl as a static library, compiled with SSL using OpenSSL - which should also be a static library. Optionally, you could use libtool to merge them into a single library.

How to build it? => https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html